# Why doesn't my client IP address appear in the netstat output?

Tags: solaris, netstat

My client is a MS Excel plug-in running on my laptop (client_machine1) that connects to a Solaris server (server1) to request some WebLogic Application running on port `28080`.

```
bash-3.2$ set | grep SSH_CONNECTION
SSH_CONNECTION='<client_machine1 IP Address> 64134 <Server1 IP Address> 22'

bash-3.2$ netstat -a | grep <client_machine1 IP address>
<Server1 FQDN>.28080 <client_machine1 IP address>.49592  260836      0 49950      0 FIN_WAIT_2
<Server1 FQDN>.28080 <client_machine1 IP address>.49595  261216      0 49950      0 FIN_WAIT_2
<Server1 FQDN>.28080 <client_machine1 IP address>.49596  261216      0 49950      0 FIN_WAIT_2
<Server1 FQDN>.ssh <client_machine1 IP address>.64134  65024    135 49950      0 ESTABLISHED
```

During my client session, I kept checking the output of `netstat -a | grep <client_machine1 IP address>` to see if my client's IP address shows up. Only for a brief period of time I was able to see it and capture the above output. For the rest of the time I can only see the ssh connection entry. I find this confusing as the client session is active at that time and data exchange is in progress.

Am I missing something here..? I also tried `lsof | grep <client_machine1 IP address>` but that doesn't return anything.

Comment: Did you try this again with netstat -n ? Just to be sure that the host isn't resolved to the name at some time and your grep doesn't work?

Comment: @echox - okay I will check that. Just realized that I am connecting to a virtual server that internally forwards my request to server1. I guess  I saw my IP when I tried to directly connect to server1..

Comment: `lsof -n -i :28080`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a `netstat -a` you get just the hostnames and names of services.

#### Example

```
$ netstat -a|head -20
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State      
tcp        0      0 *:sunrpc                    *:*                         LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdomain:ipp   *:*                         LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 *:db-lsp                    *:*                         LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 *:58460                     *:*                         LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 *:17501                     *:*                         LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 *:lv-jc                     *:*                         LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 *:ellpack                   *:*                         LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 greeneggs.bubba.net:37050   stackoverflow.com:http      TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 greeneggs.bubba.net:34320   stackoverflow.com:http      ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 greeneggs.bubba.net:34223   stackoverflow.com:http      ESTABLISHED
```

There is nothing in this output that will match your IP address, since it's just names. If you want to forgo showing names and just show the numbers, use the `-n` switch to `netstat`:

```
$ netstat -an|head -20
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58460               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17501               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2143                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2025                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.20:36188          198.252.206.16:80           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.20:37112          198.252.206.25:80           TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.20:37116          198.252.206.25:80           TIME_WAIT
```

Comment: Thanks. Marked as the right answer as the examples help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `netstat -n` if you're going to `grep` by IP address. Otherwise, you get your machine's host *name* in the `netstat` output.

Comment: +1. Thanks this helps. This helped but seems my request goes through a proxy so my client never connects to the remote server directly and so won't appear in netstat.